# How to configure for inserting spaces instead of tabs on Visual Studio Code for Mac

Tags: editor

I begin to use Visual Studio Code. Current version is 0.3.0.
By default, Indent is inserted for tabs.
But I want to insert 4 spaces instead tabs.

I can't find the configure out the item in Preferences.

Please tell me, how to configure insert tab or space.

Answer (score 3):

Approximately since version 0.9.0 this configuration is easily reachable by modifying the following parameters in the **settings.json** file:

```
// Controls the rendering size of tabs in characters. Accepted values: "auto", 2, 4, 6, etc. If set to "auto", the value will be guessed when a file is opened.
"editor.tabSize": 4,

// Controls if the editor will insert spaces for tabs. Accepted values:  "auto", true, false. If set to "auto", the value will be guessed when a file is opened.
"editor.insertSpaces": true
```

For others settings and information visit the VS Code [help](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace) section.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is in keybindings.json. From the menu **Code** -> **Preferences** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts**

On the right hand pane you can place your key bindings, for example:

```
{"key": "ctrl+t",      "when": "editorTextFocus", "command": "editor.action.tab"}
```

though you would probably prefer something like:

```
{"key": "ctrl+t",      "when": "editorTextFocus", "command": "    "}
```

The problem is that it does not work as the documentation says it should!
See: [Customization of Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization)

Microsoft has been notified of the behavior and tab handling preferences have also been requested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope next update by Microsoft.